# Run tasks based on a future date using Swift including when app is in background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to run a task based on a scheduled Date set from UIDatePicker.

So, for example I scheduled a task tomorrow at 1:00PM, it should process this task regardless app is in foreground or background mode. If anyone, can lead me to the right direction, that would be cool!

In Android it is called AlarmManager. But it seems on iOS there seems to be none.

Comment: No way to do this

Comment: You can charge some events that will launch at exact time. But nevertheless user have to launch your app after restart.

Comment: The only solution is to use service side APNs notifications

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in general. If your app is in the foreground, you may simply set up an `NSTimer` to trigger something at desired time. If your app is in the background, though, the timer is not guaranteed to fire. You may schedule a local notification for the desired time, but that’s not an automatic solution any more, the user has to “open” the notification to run your app.